# Custom IEnumerable as ItemsSource for ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, enumerator, inotifycollectionchanged

I have a class that defines a custom GetEnumerator() function(by implementing IEnumerable<>). I use it to iterate in a contiguous manner over several `ObservableCollection<LogEvent>` that are in every TestStep. I have a private `ObservableCollection<TestStep>` that contains all the needed data.

I would like to use an instance of this class as the ItemsSource of a ListBox. However, the ListBox never gets updated when the underlying data(`ObservableCollection<LogEvent>`) is updated. Here's a sample of that class:

```
public class FlatLogViewModel : IEnumerable<LogEvent>
{
    public FlatLogViewModel(ObservableCollection<TestStep> subSteps)
    {
        m_subSteps = subSteps;            
    }

    public IEnumerator<LogEvent> GetEnumerator()
    {
        foreach (TestStep step in SubSteps)
        {
            // step.LogEvents is an ObservableCollection<LogEvent>
            foreach (LogEvent logEvent in step.LogEvents)
                yield return logEvent;
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.GetEnumerator();
    }

    private ObservableCollection<TestStep> m_subSteps;
}
```

I'm not sure if I should/can implement INotifyCollectionChanged here. How can I know if ObservableCollection has been modified?

My question is: how can I get the ListBox to display the changes happening in LogEvents(which is of type `ObservableCollection<LogEvent>`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When theObservableCollection changes, how does the ListBox know? You have to implement like you mentioned INotifyCollectionChanged and then update the ItemSource with the new enumerable data inside the event handler.

`ObservableCollection is an INotifyCollectionChanged.` Use casting

```
var collectionChanged = yourObCollection as INotifyCollectionChanged;

 if( collectionChanged !=null)
{
   collectionChanged.CollectionChanged += YourEventHandler; 
}
```

inside the handler do your own logic to update the item source

Comment: Yes but how do I detect when the underlying ObservableCollection has changed, so that I can fire the CollectionChanged event at the right moment?

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered binding to the original collection but running it through a converter in order to pull out the `LogEvent`s?

The converter should be able to simply `return subSteps.SelectMany(s => s.LogEvents)`.

Comment: I didn't think about this, I think it would work but Dan's solution seems to be exactly what I need. Thanks!